# error C2678: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting this annoying error C2678: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand.
I want to use find_if to find a divisor number and the returned value by the iterator to be added in a vector.
I would appreciate any ideas.

**Header file**

```
#ifndef SMTH_H
#define SMTH_H


#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    using std::vector;

    namespace Calculator{
        namespace Cal{

            typedef unsigned int Uint;
            typedef vector<Uint> TVint;
            typedef vector<Uint>::const_iterator TIterator;
    /..../

        class TestPrim : public Sir
            {
            protected:
                Uint _val;      
                double _stopVal;

            public:
                Uint testPrim;
                TestPrim(Uint val);
                TestPrim& operator ++();
                bool operator () (Uint divizor);
                operator Uint ();
                friend bool operator > (Uint val, const TestPrim &src);

            };
        }
    }
    #endif
```

Cpp file

```
#include <iomanip>
#include "smth.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace Calculator{
    namespace Cal{
/..../

class TestPrim;

        void Prime::CalculeazaValori(int index)
        {
            if(index > MAX_PRIME)
            {
                throw errorCheck();
            }

            if(index == 0)
            {
                _elemente.push_back(2);
                _elemente.push_back(3);
            }

            for (TestPrim testPrim = (_elemente.back() + 2); _elemente.size() < _count; ++testPrim)
            {

                TIterator it = find_if (_elemente.begin(), _elemente.end(), testPrim  );
                if (it > testPrim) //error on this line
                {
                    _elemente.push_back(testPrim);
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please **never** put a using directive or declaration in a header. I don't want extra junk brought in when I include a header.

Comment: @chris i'll keep in mind. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your operator looks like:

```
friend bool operator > (Uint val, const TestPrim &src);
```

and this is how you are using it:

```
it > testPrim
```

`it` is a `TIterator`, not a `Uint`. Presumably you meant

```
*it > testPrim
```